# How to add TouchUpInside for button in UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have the following:

```
- View
  Image View
  Image View
  - Second View
    Image View
    Image View
    MY BUTTON
```

When I go into Interface builder and try to add the TouchUpInside for "MY BUTTON" to the "Second View" it will not allow me to do so.  I can only add it to the first view.

The "Second View" is a subclass of UIView, so I pick my class in Interface Builder but it wont let me create it.

Any help in understanding this will be appreciated.

I hope I explained it ok, sorry if it is a foolish question!!

Comment: I would expect the event to be connected to an action in a view controller rather than a view subclass.

Comment: I do have a view controller that has a member variable to my UIView subclass, so do I connect the action to the view controller and then pass it to the view?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "pass it to the view".  In general, view controllers are the place for any view-related logic that's not directly connected to how things look on the screen.

Comment: I see what you are saying and that is what I have (i think)... I have a view controller, but then i have a view that has my ui elements, ie, a button, so when I say "pass it to the view" I am asking, do I respond to the TouchUpInside in the view controller, but then call a method of my UIView to handle the ui related tasks for that view?

Comment: That's the opposite : the UIButton in your view hierarchy GETS the action, and passes it to an `IBAction` (which is just a `void` method in one object's header that can be linked from Interface Builder). So 1- Declare `IBAction` in your ViewController's header 2- select `TouchUpInside` from the button in your XIB, and drag to the 'File's owner' (the controller in your case) where you should see your IBAction method appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done it and uploaded an image for you. Specify the second view class and then right click on the second view it will show the IBAction of in SecondView and then connect it.
here blue color view is second view with class SecondView.

[image]

Comment: YES, perfect!!!  That's what I was wondering how to do!!  One question, to make this work, I had to add the IBAction prototype to the header file manually... is that correct?

Comment: Yeah you have to put it in SecondView.h file. You can also use xcode and ctrl + drag to create a connection.

Answer (score 1):

You want to choose a Button through xib file..rounded rect or custom. And declare in header file

```
IBOUTLet UIbutton * btn;
```

then action declare a method ...

```
-(IBAction)btnaction{
    //write your code
}
```

Then connectivity in the nib file.